# Python Basics - ps.tekken() = 'Object has no Attribute'

Tags: python

I've just started a Python course out of general interest in the area. I've made this very basic code on the topic of consoles (the text is mostly nonsense).

Everything works except the commands `ps.tekken()` and `gamecube.mario()` which give me the common error of:

> AttributeError: 'console' object has no attribute 'tekken'

I know I'm doing something obviously wrong here, but am unable to figure out what when I compare this with other code. The indenting seems fine. Thank you!

```
class console:
    def __init__(self, number, games):
        self.number = number
        self.games = games

    def poweron(self):
        print ('Powering on the unit. The console is {} years old and I have {} games'.format(self.number, self.games))

    def poweroff(self):
        print ('Powering off the unit. Goodbye.')

class gc(console):

    def mario(self):
        print('Lets play Mario!')

class playstation(console):

    def tekken(self):
        print('Lets play Tekken!')

# Create a ps (Playstation) and Gamecube #

ps = console('4','7')


gamecube = console('3','2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how to create `PlayStation` and `Gamecube` objects. You need to do like so:

```
# Create a ps (Playstation) and Gamecube #
ps = playstation('4','7')
gamecube = gc('3','2')

ps.tekken()
# Lets play Tekken!

gamecube.mario()
# Lets play Mario!
```

You should know that class names are Camel-cased by convention. So, you should use `PlayStation` instead of `playstation` and `Gc` instead of `gc` and `Console` instead of `console`

Answer (score 0):

tekkin and mario are built in subclass of console, not belonged to console.
You create two instance, ps and gamecube, from class console. Of course, they don't have those methods/functions.

So you need to create instance from gc or playstation, not from console.

```py
ps = playstation('4','7')
gamecube = gc('3','2')
```

Besides that, you may need to define one initialization function in subclass of console if you have something special to initialize.

```py
def __init__(self, number, games):
    super().__init__(number, games)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help in this basic matter :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to develop a Heritance exercise, isn't it?

You can't call method `tekken()` from a ps instance since `class playstation` is not linked correctly to his parent (`console`)

Try this:

```
class gc(console): 
    #Link  gc class to parent throug __init__ and super() intialization.
    def __init__(self, number, games):
        super().__init__(number, games)

    def mario(self):
        print('Lets play Mario!')
```

And then call the method mario() with gc class:

```
ps = gc('4','7')
ps.mario()
```

Regards.